# How to check what policy gives access to specific resource (kinesis data stream)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis

I wanted to check which resources are putting records into kinesis data stream but I didn't find any information about it, so is there any possibility to check who has access to write to kinesis data stream? How can I check which policy grants/denies access to specific resource on AWS?

I tried searching through IAM, kinesis and CloudTrail but I didn't see any informations I looked for.

Comment: CloudTrail captures all API calls for Kinesis Data Streams as events. Do you have CloudTrail configured and do you see KDS events?

Comment: @jarmod Unfortunately, cloud trail doesn't capture all API calls (for example it doesn't capture PutRecords), https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/logging-using-cloudtrail.html

Comment: Hmm, I was quoting from the 2nd sentence on that exact page where it states "CloudTrail captures all API calls for Kinesis Data Streams as events" but I see that it doesn't include PutRecords in the list further down the page. That's disappointing.